# library('FSelector') hangs my R session, any clue?

Tags: java, r

I just did a `install.packages('FSelector')` it does what it is supposed to do, install the package and all its dependencies. Then when I do `library('FSelector')` it does nothing, it keeps like loading, but does nothing. It never returns to the `>`prompt

So I cancelled the R Studio session and started over with the same results.

I thought it might be a Java problem since FSelector has dependencies on `rJava` package. I had Java 7, so I uninstalled it and installed Java 8 Update 73, which currently is the most recent version, via a manual download to get the 64 bit version that corresponds to the R version I'm using. Tried again and got the same result.

I really don't know how to troubleshoot or if I require anything else. I'm running:

- Windows 10
- R 3.2.1 64 bits
- RStudio version 0.99.448
- Java 8 Update 73 64 bits

Comment: Does `library(rJava)` runs? Do you have all the dependencies installed? `install.packages('FSelector', dep = TRUE)`.

Comment: Yes, it runs with a warning: `package ‘rJava’ was built under R version 3.2.3`, normally I don't have any problem with this kind of warnings. Do you think I should update R from 3.2.1 to 3.2.3?

Comment: Yes, I would recommend so. Then run `update.packages(checkBuilt = TRUE)`.

Comment: I ran the `install.packages('FSelector', dep=TRUE)` tried again, no luck. I'll update R right away, and see what happens, thanks!

Comment: I might have another problem. I'm trying to use the `installr` library, but when I do an `updateR()` does the same, stays there, doing apparently nothing. Could it be signaling a permissions problem?

Comment: Mental note: Use RGui not RStudio. `installr` package is working now.

Comment: Interesting to know.

Comment: OK, I installed R 3.2.3 which is the latest version. There must be a problem with my RStudio installation. `library('FSelector')` still does nothing, but when running on RGui it works as it should

Comment: Oh man... problem was with RStudio. I updated from 0.99.448 to 0.99.878 and it is working now. Thank you very much for your guidance, was great to troubleshoot and update my R environment!

Comment: Please write down an answer. It might help others facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion from my experience is: when using something related to `rJava`, it's likely that R would crush some time. `FSelector` is easy to run out of memory with large data set. It's highly likely that you'll have set a higher memory limit when using it in production.

It's better to run it from command line, e.g. `Rscript someScriptThatRunsRSelector.R`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes but this answer may help other people whose problem is not due to R version. I've had that problems before.

Comment: The problem was due to RStudio version

Comment: I am not sure why you seem to be not friendly on this. I am just a guy trying to help people around here and give suggestion. Imagine a people having this problem but the problem was not due to RStudio version. I am here to give them more directions and possibly some more advise on using FSelector. For example, if the data set is large and it's very likely your r session will hang there due to memory management issues with FSelector. It's also likely that you'll need to add `options(java.parameters = "-Xmx6g")` if you rJava runs out of limited memory. I think all these would help other people.

Comment: Guys, I agree that this answer comes a bit late, but it is very valuable also. Before upgrading everything (Java, R, RStudio) there was no way to tell what was causing the problem, it could have been a Java problem (I understand that Java 32 bit doesn't behave well with R 64 bits), and the problem looked like that: it just takes too much time to load. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, I'm very thankful to **Pascal** who helped me to troubleshoot this problem. The problem was caused I don't know if by an outdated RStudio or a corrupted RStudio installation, anyway, reinstalling RStudio made everything work again.

In the process I learn several other things:

- You must have a Java environment that matches your R installation, that is, if you're using R 64 bit, you must install Java 64 bit. The Java page (https://www.java.com/) its so poorly developed that won't recognize if you're using a 32 or 64 bits OS, so to install the 64 bit version you must do it manually using this other page: http://www.java.com/es/download/manual.jsp
- To update R the easy way in Windows, you should install the `installr` package, here is a pretty good tutorial on how to use it: http://www.r-bloggers.com/updating-r-from-r-on-windows-using-the-installr-package/ The good thing abour installr is that it will copy and check all the installed packages, so it is quite straight forward.
- Finally, to update RStudio is at easy as download the latest version and install it over the old installation.

I really don't know what caused the problem, but upgrading everything solved the issue.